# How do I have a default selected enum using EnumDropDownListFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

In my MVC5 app I have a page which shows logs.

I have a drop down to filter logging levels, which are:

- All
- Debug
- Error
- Info

I have these defined an an enum called ErrorLevel:

```
public enum ErrorLevel
{
    [Description("All")]
    All = 0,

    [Description("Debug")]
    Debug = 1,

    [Description("Error")]
    Error = 2,

    [Description("Info")]
    Info = 3
}
```

I am rendering these in my view like this:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Level)
```

> The drop down value is blank when the page first renders - how do I have `All` as the default selected **enum value** when the page first renders?

I've spent 20 minutes looking for how to do this but can't find how to do it, can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you can easily do that, in the constructor of the model class within controller .

**Here is the complete  example:**

Sample Modal Class:

```
 public class SampleModel
    {
        public ErrorLevel level{ get; set; }
    }
```

Enum:

```
  public enum ErrorLevel
{
    [Description("All")]
    All = 0,

    [Description("Debug")]
    Debug = 1,

    [Description("Error")]
    Error = 2,

    [Description("Info")]
    Info = 3
}
```

Some Controller :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        SampleModel samplemodel= new SampleModel {level= level.All};  //you can set any value which you want as default
        return View("View",samplemodel);
    }
}
```

Hope the above code was helpful

Thanks

Karthik

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting the Enum in the Model before it gets called in the view.

**Controller**

```
 model.Level = ErrorLevel.All;
```